# How to teach parents to apply early childhood interventions to improve cognitive outcomes in children?

Tags: developmental-psychology, motivation, educational-psychology

I've watched the ["My Brilliant Brain: Born Genius"](http://natgeotv.com/asia/my-brilliant-brain/about) documentary where they refer to the [Abecedarian Project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abecedarian_Early_Intervention_Project), in that investigation, a group of children that were exposed to early childhood education observed long-term benefits, such as higher scores in intelligence tests than those children that weren't exposed to early education.

Are there any peer-reviewed or follow-up studies on the optimal ways to teach new parents on how to obtain similar results?

Comment: I am not sure where you are going with this question.  The optimal way to achieve similar results would be to get children in Early Years Education would it not?  I don't know about other countries, but here in the UK there is free Early Years Education available in registered and approved pre-schools for 15 hours per week each child soon to be raised to 30 hours per week

Comment: I agree with @Chris. There's a lot of different interventions that happen at a societal level rather than a personal level. Does your question intend to ignore these? If yes, why?

Comment: @Seanny123 [Early adoption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_adopter) might be one reason, nothing to do with early education though. The benefits early adopters get surpass those of waiting for everybody to catch up IMHO.

Comment: Further to my previous comment in June, there are unpublished reports unavailable to the public as they contain personal information I have seen as a volunteer within a pre-school, which shows the benefits of early years education.  These reports cover early adopted and non-adopted children

Comment: @Chris I think we are both rooting for the same thing, the difference is that I don't have access to those reports you mentioned, nor to those pre-school programs.